# How to stop specific block of code not to execute hen the respective method is called more than once

Tags: angular

I have requirement like the **Block Code** which I mentioned in code should not be executed when I call getData() method in setFlag() method or else how can I stop pushing the data to searchTextData object

Below is the code

Component class

```
searchTextData: IdObject[];


getData(projName: string) {
this.allCombinationFalse = false;
this.blockData = [];

this.service
  .getDataDetails(projName)
  .map(resp => {
    const that = this;
    resp["dataList"].forEach(data => {
      data['blockName'] = '';
      if (data['exists'] === false) {
        data['a'] = false;
        data['aSelected'] = false;
        that.errorList.push(data);


      }
    });
    return resp;
  })
  .subscribe(resp => {

    this.blockData = resp["dataList"];


    const listValid = this.blockData .filter(t => {
      return t.exists === true;
    });
    if (listValid.length > 0) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        (<any>document).body
          .querySelector('#blockName_' + listValid[0].blockId)
          .focus();
      }, 700);
    }

   // Executable Code based on condition(Block Code) 
    resp["eng"].forEach(e =>{
      e['name'] = e['fName'] + ' ' + e['Mname'];
      this.searchTextData.push(eng);
      })

  });  //end
```

}

```
setFlag()
{

let obj:any;
    obj ={
      projName: this.projNameSelected.siteName,
      combination : true
    };
    this.service.setFlag(obj).subscribe(resp=>{
            this.getData(this.projNameSelected.projName);
    })
```

}

Comment: how about use flag?
The easiest and simplest way.

Comment: Yes I got this later and I followed the same in code and it worked, Thanks - @Talg123